# get currentUrl from current view and pass it to controller to redirect user back to the URL he comes from after making some logic in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How to pass the ReturnUrl from View to the following controller, Using Asp.MVc.Core.6

```
 public IActionResult SetLanguage(string culture, string returnUrl)
{
   
    var _returnUrl = returnUrl;

    Response.Cookies.Append(
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.DefaultCookieName,
        CookieRequestCultureProvider.MakeCookieValue(new RequestCulture(culture)),
        new CookieOptions {Expires = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(1)}
    );

    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
    {
        return Redirect(returnUrl);
        return LocalRedirect(_returnUrl);
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    }
```

The view

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't paste images of code. Paste actual code. Please give debugging details. A [mcve], what you expect to happen and what's actually happening

Comment: @JHBonarius , simply how to get currentUrl of the page from current view and pass it to the controller .( so later I can user the currentUrl to redirect user back to the URL he comes from after making some logic inside my controller )

Comment: Put it _in_ the question please. It's not for me, but for everybody reading it. You don't want them to also have to read the comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use

```
asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path"
```

It will do the trick

Comment: that is weird what is the difference `@HttpContext.Request.Path`  and `@Context.Request.Path`